# Node JS + Grunt-sonar-runner + Code Coverage not showing

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sonarqube, mocha.js

I created a REST service in node js and wrote the test cases using mocha. I have been able to generate the code coverage using istanbul and is working absolutely fine. Now my requirement is to show the code coverage using Sonar. The code compliance violations are getting listed as expected. But the code coverage is not getting generated in sonar. I doubt there is something wrong with the gruntfile.js configuration. Currently, I generate the code compliance violation by copying the source inside the grunt-sonar-runner folder within node_modules and execute grunt-sonar-runner. My current folder structure is as shown below :

```
<ProjectRoot>

|--server.js
|--[test]
|--|--serverTest.js

|--[node_modules]
|--|--[grunt-sonar-runner]
|--|--|--[src]
|--|--|--|--server.js
```

In the gruntfile.js,

```
grunt.initConfig({
    jshint: {
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            'tasks/*.js',
            'test/*.js'
        ],
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
        }
    },

    // Before generating any new files, remove any previously-created files.
    clean: {
        tests: ['tmp']
    },

    // Configuration to be run (and then tested).
    sonarRunner: {
        analysis: {
            options: {
                debug: true,
                separator: '\n',
                sonar: {
                    host: {
                        url: 'http://localhost:9000'
                    },
                    jdbc: {
                        url: 'jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar',
                        username: 'sonar',
                        password: 'sonar'
                    },
                    projectKey: 'sonar:grunt-sonar-runner:0.1.0',
                    projectName: 'Grunt Sonar Runner',
                    projectVersion: '0.10',
                    sources: ['src'].join(','),
                    language: 'js',
                    sourceEncoding: 'UTF-8'
                }
            }
        },
        dryRun: {
            options: {
                dryRun: true,
                debug: true,
                separator: '\n',
                sonar: {
                    host: {
                        url: 'http://localhost:9000'
                    },
                    jdbc: {
                        url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar',
                        username: 'sonar',
                        password: 'sonar'
                    },
                    projectKey: 'sonar:grunt-sonar-runner:0.1.0',
                    projectName: 'Grunt Sonar Runner',
                    projectVersion: '0.10',
                    sources: ['src'].join(','),
                    exclusions: '**/R.js'
                }
            }
        }
    },

    // Unit tests.
    mochaTest: {
        test: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'spec'
            },
            src: ['test/**/*.js'],

        }
    }

});
```

we have two sections --> analysis and dryRun. What is this dryRun ?

Just outside that, we have a key called mochaTest.

While running mocha with istanbul, I am getting coverage reports generated in the project root inside a folder called coverage. Unfortunately it is not getting listed in sonar. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Noble

Comment: Shouldn't you provide options.sonar.javascript.lcov.reportPath? https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-sonar-runner

Comment: Yes.. Thanks for the reply. The issue got resolved. Uninstalled grunt-sonar-runner module. Just had to define a sonar-roject.properties in the project root folder. Inside that properties file, we can specify the relative path to the lcov.info generated by istanbul. After starting up the sonar qube server, just run sonar-runner (provided sonar runner is present in the system path). Sonar reports will be visible in sonar dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to define a sonar-roject.properties in the project root folder. Inside that properties file, we can specify the relative path to the lcov.info generated by istanbul. After starting up the sonar qube server, just run sonar-runner (provided sonar runner is present in the system path). Sonar reports will be visible in sonar dashboard